# QVariantList.append() merges list instead of nesting

Tags: list, qt5.5, qvariant

When I try to nest a `QVariantList` inside another `QVariantList`, the result is the flat merge of the two lists, instead of a sub-list.

Demo code:

```
QVariantList container;

QVariantList nested() << "bar" << "baz";

container.append("foo");  // or container << "foo";
container.append(nested); // or container << nested;
```

What I obtain (indentations are mine):

```
QVariant(QVariantList,
  QVariant(QString, "foo"),
  QVariant(QString, "bar"),
  QVariant(QString, "baz"),
)
```

What I would expect:

```
QVariant(QVariantList,
  QVariant(QString, "foo"),
  QVariant(QVariantList, 
    QVariant(QString, "bar"),
    QVariant(QString, "baz")
  )
)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found solution by myself.

This is due the QList's `append` overload:

> void QList::append(const QList & value)
>
> This is an overloaded function.
>
> Appends the items of the value list to this list.

The solution is append item using `insert` method:

```
QVariantList l;
l.insert(l.size(), QVariant());
```

Comment: You can also use the [`push_back`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html#push_back) alias that has no special overload for `QList`: `l.push_back(other_list);`
This relies on a "API design hack" from Qt but at least it does not need the size.